# I have a e bike tricycle. Its butchered. I need a wiring diagram

Tags: road-bike, motor

So I found a Segway trike at the dump. It's all there but it looks like some body tried to turn it into a 48 volt system and I do believe that it was originally a 36volt. My next suspicion is that that the motor is also not for a 36volt, its more like a 750watt by the looks of it, so I'm wondering how can I function test the wheel motor without a plug on the end? Also, is there a way I can do away with the module and somehow jimmyrig the thing to the throttle with some alternative circiutry with regards to any electric bike motor that resides in the wheel itself? Is there any possible way to just hook up the battery to a manifold of wires from the cluster of wires from the motor to the battery to the controller or throttle?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  I'm afraid that advice for rewiring electrical power systems isn't really our strength.  You might want to try a forum dedicated to electronics.

Answer (score 1):

You're right - you really do need a wiring diagram or more info on that specific brand/model.

Everything depends on the design and the parts.  So start by googling up all the part numbers and see what you can find.   It is almost certainly a motor bought from a wholesaler and integrated into the bike, so the specs should exist somewhere.

The few ebikes I've worked with have had 3-phase AC motors, which all have three equal sized wires going into the hub, possibly with some optional thinner signalling wires.   As such you cannot hook DC to an AC motor and have it spin.

There must be a "box" that converts the 36V or 48V  DC from the battery to AC to run the motor.  That function may be inside the battery receiver in/on the frame, or it may be a separate box.

---

Some searching for "segway trike" returns decidedly non-bicycle results like this - a lack of pedals means this isn't any form of cycle, and falls into a gap tending toward electric motorcycle or "assistive technology"

[image]  "Segway SE-3 Patroller"

Please add photos of what you have now, including an overview as well as closeups of specific relevant parts, like the controller box, throttle, motor, battery, and any labels.

Otherwise search through results like https://www.google.com/search?q=Segway+trike&tbm=isch and try find something that looks the same as yours.